# Create Histogram, grouping by a column and then sum by another in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, histogram

I have a dataset, data, with the following values:

```
               ID                TIME                         Duration   
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        0 sec
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec                    
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:13 AM        1 sec
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:14 AM        0 sec
```

I wish to create a histogram that groups the ID, and sums the Duration, for the following, which will have the ID as the X axis , and Sum on the Y axis, using ggplot.

```
               ID        Sum

               A         1
               B         1
```

I have used the following code:

```
              library(dplyr)
              library(ggplot)
              library(qplot)




            sumdata<-df %>% groupby(ID) %>% SUM(Duration)

            qplot(df,
            geom="histogram",
            binwidth = 0.5,  
            main = "Histogram for Duration", 
            xlab = "ID"
            ylab = "Duration")
```

I am still researching. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please `dput` data frame in your question.

Comment: try `sumdata <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(sums = sum(Duration)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = sums)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Thank you, the following code would group_by ID and then perform a SUM?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Yes, it does select all other columns.  Here the `.` on the lhs of `~` signifies all the other columns (assuming they are all numeric)

Comment: ok thank you, so I am wanting to sum the duration column, while grouping by the ID. Is this correct?  aggregate(ID, df, FUN = sum) Or do I have to use groupbyID first then sum?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. If it is just a single column `aggregate(duration ~ ID, df, FUN = sum)` where ID is the grouping column

Comment: Ok I see thank you, and I can use this plot to reveal a bar graph? library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Duration)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")    something similar

Comment: Hi Akrun, when I run the bargraph I get this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ID' not found   I have installed and loaded the ggplot packages etc

Comment: I think I must do this: ggplot(data = df, aes(df$ID, df$Duration)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: It
 would be `ggplot(df, aes(ID, Duration)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Hi @Akrun, can I still use this code if I wish to keep the TIME column?  df1<-aggregate(Duration ~ TIME ~ ID, df, FUN = sum)

Comment: @TanishaHudson If it is a `POSIXct` class and not `POSIXlt`

Comment: Ok @Akrun, I was just making sure that this: df1<-aggregate(Duration ~ TIME ~ ID, df, FUN = sum)   is the correct and proper way to write this. I will check the datetime format. If it is not POSIXct, can I just convert it?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. You can use `as.POSIXct` if it is `POSIXlt` class (this is stored as a `list`)

Comment: ok thank you @akrun, I was just wondering how to preserve the TIME column in the:  df1<-aggregate(Duration ~ TIME ~ ID, df, FUN = sum)  command. Can I add multiple columns within this command like how I just did?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Do you need `aggregate(Duration ~ Time + ID, df, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Ok yes, @akrun Overall I am trying to plot this dataset within Plotly. I want to have the Time and ID on the X axis and the Duration on the Y axis.

Comment: @TanishaHudson Not clear about how the x axis would look like

Comment: Ok @akrun that is fine. I will have hovertext from plotly display the TIME, however the IDs will be printed on the X axis

Comment: @TanishaHudson I guess you posted another question about plot_ly.  Can you pleaes update theere

Comment: Ok I will. Thank you @akrun

Comment: Hi @Akrun , the class is POSIXct , but when I perform this: aggregate(Duration ~ Time + ID, df, FUN = sum) the Time column is preserved, however the Duration does not SUM. I can create a new question , I just wanted to ask quickly

Comment: @TanishaHudson If the 'Time' values are all unique, then the number of rows per group would. be 1. i.e. can you `aggregate(Duration ~ Time + ID, df, FUN = length)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ggplot2` for this.

Summarise data like this before plotting:

```
library(dplyr)
 df <- df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_all(sum)
```

Then create a plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Duration)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error, for the first command: Error in Summary.POSIXct(1579113995, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  'sum' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: Can you please add reproducible example of your data? Or, you can use `aggregate` solution given above and then use `ggplot2` to plot a graph.

Comment: Thank you, I had to do this: I think I must do this: ggplot(data = df, aes(df$ID, df$Duration)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")   To specify the columns I believe

Comment: You don't need to do `df$ID` within `aes`. It should just work with column name `ID`.

Comment: Ok, it kept saying Object not found when I did this - but when I specified the dataframe and column it worked. I did aes(df$ID, df$Duration)) rather than, aes(x = ID, y = Duration)

Comment: See this example: `df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A",  "A", "B", "B"), Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Duration = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0))`. `library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Duration)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. It works on my machine. I'm using `ggplot2` version ‘3.2.1’.

Comment: Ok I will try, maybe it is my values. Thank you.

Comment: are we able to make the words diagonal on the X axis? (the words in my x axis are very long in my dataset)

Comment: Try this: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = ID, y = Duration)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()`. It'll change x-axis columns to y-axis and can solve your problem.